# SQL Server triggers duplicating output

Tags: sql, sql-server, triggers

I've been asked to set up a trigger in SQL Server that will write out any changes made to a table to a log. Easy enough to do on it's own, but the problem I'm running into is when multiple values are changed in a single record. Rather than run both insert statements separately, it seems to be running the first one multiple times. Or at least that's what it appears to be doing.

Here's the SQL I thought would work:

```
IF UPDATE(Z1)
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO RVP.mtx.Log(Y, M, B, D, ColumnName, ColumnValue, DTM)
        SELECT i.Y, i.M, i.B, i.D, 'Z1', i.Z1, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
        FROM inserted i
END

IF UPDATE(Z2)
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO RVP.mtx.Log(Y, M, B, D, ColumnName, ColumnValue, DTM)
        SELECT j.Y, j.M, j.B, j.D, 'Z2', j.Z2, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
        FROM inserted j
END
```

And here's how I was expecting the data to look:

| Column Y | Column M | Column B | Column D | ColumnName | ColumnValue |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 10 | 11 | 12 | 13 | Z1 | 14 |
| 10 | 11 | 12 | 13 | Z2 | 15 |

However, when the trigger gets activated it appears to be running the first block twice, assuming both fields Z1 and Z2 have data in them. This is what the trigger outputs:

| Column Y | Column M | Column B | Column D | ColumnName | ColumnValue |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 10 | 11 | 12 | 13 | Z1 | 14 |
| 10 | 11 | 12 | 13 | Z1 | 14 |

Comment: Triggers are **highly vendor-specific** - so please add a tag to specify whether you're using `mysql`, `postgresql`, `sql-server`, `oracle` or `db2` - or something else entirely.

Comment: What `UPDATE` statement are you executing?

Comment: @marc_s - Apologies, I had no idea that was even a thing. I'm a little new to the whole SQL game. Added a tag for sql-server.

Comment: @Charlieface - It's not a direct update statement. This trigger is meant to fire whenever someone edits the database via a linked table in Microsoft Access.

Comment: Consier changing this approach to use temporal tables instead. It basically does what you're attempting to do out of the box

Comment: @ZoharPeled - First, thank you for letting me know about those. I never knew they existed and that will absolutely save me a lot of time in the near future. However, in this case it won't work. The end goal of this table I'm working on is to use it as a way to approve/deny changes rather than just let them all go through to the primary table.

Comment: are you trying to implement a kind of change data capture log? if that's your goal, SQL Server already provides an out of the box solution for that: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/track-changes/about-change-data-capture-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver16